# participial construction usage question - 'although' being omission

Tags: participle-phrases

**Original Text:**
Although gamblers are the most prone to this, it equally applies to business during bubbles and to people who gain sudden attention from the public.

If I change the above sentence into the participial construction, is it grammatical correct?
(To emphasize the meaning, I do not omit the conjunction.)

**Although gamblers **(being)** the most prone to this**, ~.

Comment: [correction: "it applies equally to x" is better]

Answer (score 1):

**In order to reduce an adverbial clause, it must have the [same subject](https://www.cambridge.org/elt/blog/2020/01/07/reducing-adverbial-time-clauses/) as the independent clause.**

'Although gamblers being the most prone to this' does not work grammatically here because it does not describe 'it': the two clauses have different subjects.

Here's an example where you can reduce the adverbial clause:

> Though I was hungry, I didn't eat lunch.

Reduced to:

> Though hungry, I didn't eat lunch.

In this case, the subject of both clauses is "I" so you can reduce one. However, in your example:

> Although gamblers are the most prone to this, it equally applies to
> business during bubbles and to people who gain sudden attention from
> the public.

The subject of the first clause is **gamblers**. The second is **it**.

Therefore, this is not grammatically correct.